# How to filter by item contained in a list in realm react native?

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm doing the following query:

```
realm.objects('Maker').filtered("categories CONTAINS $0", categoryObject)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Only 'equal' and 'not equal' operators are supported for object comparison
```

And here's my schema:

```
{ 
name: 'MakerOption',
primaryKey: 'serverId',
properties: {
  serverId: 'int',
  name: 'string',
  categories: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Category'},
}

{
name: 'Category',
primaryKey: 'serverId',
properties: {
  serverId: 'int',
  name: 'string'
}
```

The documentation is quite sparse on this subject. Is there an alternative method for doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Filtering by properties on linked or child objects can be done by specifying a keypath in the query e.g. `car.color == 'blue'`

So you are looking for the following query:

```
realm.objects('Maker').filtered("categories.serverId == $0", categoryObject.serverId)
```